# how to compile lists.v in coq?

Tags: coq

I'm using the assistant proof COQ, my first question would be about the Induction.v file, why do we use `Require Export Basics`, instead of `Require Import basics`?  Also why does it work when we make `Export basics.v`, even if I changed the name of basics to `Mybasics.v`?

What does `Require Export Basics.` do? Does it import or export?

I tried to execute lists.v after compiling the induction.v but it doesn't work, it says

> Unable to locate library Induction.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on software foundation? You need to add the folder to COQPATH. since proof general has handled that, i bet you are using coqide, aren't you?

The rest of your question can all be resolved by consulting the coq ref manual: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/toc.html .

Comment: it's another advise which I don't find it should go to the answer: it's unaffordable if you try to ask every single question you encounter while learning coq. documentation is always your first friend. you need to learn to figure out how things work up to a level.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between `Require Import` and `Require Export` can be found here: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/vernacular.html#hevea_command115

Providing more information about compilation (*e.g.* whether you were using command line or code editor, Coq version, textbook version *etc.*) could be useful for resolving your issue.